# Sorting alphabetically the first elements of an array like - arr[name][image]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, discord.js, alphabetical

I have an array in json with 100 images in the format bellow:

```
[{"name":"one","image":"one.jpeg"},
 {"name":"two","image":"two.jpeg"},
 {"name":"three","image":"three.jpeg"}]
```

I want to print all the "name" elements in form of a list but not the images.

I tried converting the json to string in the code bellow. I also would like to sort it alphabetically.
I think I need a loop? or is there a better method?

```
if (message.content === '!list') {
    const list= commandArray[0];
    const myJSON = JSON.stringify(list);
    message.channel.send(myJSON);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first convert the JSON to an array using `JSON.parse()` and then I am sorting the images with a custom compare function that simply sorts in an ascending order by the `name` field. Then I map through the sorted array and return a new array containing only the `name` field from each element, and then I print it.

```js
let images_json = '[{"name":"alpha","image":"alpha.jpeg"}, {"name":"delta","image":"delta.jpeg"},{"name":"charlie","image":"charlie.jpeg"}]';
let images = JSON.parse(images_json)
console.log(images); //printing to console before sort

images.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (b.name > a.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
console.log(images); //printing to console after sort

let images_names = images.map(img => img.name);
console.log(images_names) //printing only the names of the images
```